# How to pass Camel VM messages between multiple Spring Boot applications in Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-artemis, spring-camel

We have an application stack, deployed in Tomcat, that consists of several Spring Boot applications.  As part of our operations, we want to send some messages to a vm endpoint, where a camel route will consume those messages and then publish them to a JMS topic for any of the other Spring Boot applications that are interested in messages on that topic.

When I start the application stack, there are three spring boot apps that utilize camel, and I see camel start properly in the logs.  But when one of the apps sends a message to the vm endpoint, the route that consumes from that endpoint and routes the messages to the jms topic does not seem to get that message.  I have placed the `camel-core` jar in my tomcat lib directory.  In the spring boot maven plugin configuration, I have specified an exclusion of the camel-core jar.  Oddly enough, that jar is in the `WEB-INF/lib` of the war anyway!  So I have stopped Tomcat, removed that jar from the exploded war, and restarted Tomcat, but that does not change the behavior of the messaging.

Here are the versions that we are using:

- Spring Boot 2.3.1
- Camel 3.4.2
- Tomcat 8.5.5

The first spring boot app that links everything together, with the camel route that consumes from the vm endpoint and produces that message on the jms topic is our "routing engine".  It uses `camel-spring-boot-starter`, `spring-boot-starter-artemis`, `camel-vm-starter`, `artemis-jms-server` and `camel-jms-starter`.  Its `RouteBuilder`'s configure method looks like this:

```
from("vm:task")
    .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "********** Received task message");
    .to("jms:topic:local.private.task")
    .routeId("taskToJms");
```

The app that produces messages to the vm endpoint uses `camel-spring-boot-starter` and `camel-vm-starter`.  In that app, it has a `@Service` class that receives a `ProducerTemplate` that is auto-wired in the constructor.  When the application invokes this component to send the message, I see a line in the logs that says

```
o.a.c.impl.engine.DefaultProducerCache (169) - >>>> vm://task Exchange[]
```

so it appears that the message is being produced and sent properly to the vm endpoint.  However, I see no indication that it has been received/consumed in the routing engine's camel route, since the route's log line is not logging anything, and since I see no other indications of receiving the message in the log.  The strange thing is that I am not getting the error of not having any consumers on the vm:task endpoint that I was getting before I put the camel-core jar in tomcat's lib directory.

Am I doing anything obviously wrong?  How can I get the spring boot maven plugin to really exclude camel-core?  And why are the messages (sent to the vm endpoint) not being consumed by the route in the routing engine?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: I was able to keep camel-core out of the war files by adding an exclusion to the configuration of the war plugin, but I was still not able to consume the message on the vm endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post the answer, or at least "an" answer, for anyone who might have found themselves in the puzzling situation that I found myself in.

In short, the answer is that it is best to avoid trying to send VM messages across separate contexts within one big JVM like Tomcat.  Instead, use something like JMS.  I used Artemis, and I stood up an embedded broker in one of the spring boot apps in tomcat.  In other apps (that will be clients), I needed to connect to the embedded artemis server, which requires that you add a `@Configuration` class (in the module that stands up the embedded broker) that implements `ArtemisConfigurationCustomizer`:

```
@Configuration
public class ArtemisConfig implements ArtemisConfigurationCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(final org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.Configuration configuration) {
        configuration.addConnectorConfiguration("nettyConnector", new TransportConnfiguration(NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName()));
        configuration.addAcceptorConfiguration(new TransportConfiguration(NettyAcceptorFactory.class.getName()));
    }
}
```

That lets your other stuff connect to the embedded Artemis broker.  Also, you do not have to worry about upgrading camel-core jars in your tomcat shared lib folder when you upgrade camel to a different version.  It's good to keep things simple for maintenance purposes!

Anyway, I hope this helps somebody else who might find themselves here someday.